# IF with multiple conditions Java

Tags: java

I have fullnames like

**Elizabeth Smith Brown** and 
**Li xial Ping**    in some file

My task is to check the characters between (firstname and middlenamr) and (middlename and lastname)

I found distance by using someother framework.Now i am checking characters between strings like the foloowing

```
if (distancebetweenmiddlenameandfirstname==1&distancebetweenfamilynameandmiddlename==1)
   {
      fis.skip(fn.end);
      n = fis.read();//Reading character between firstname and middlename
      c = (char)n;
      fis.skip(mn.end);
      l = fis.read();//Reading character between middlename and lastname
      ch = (char)l;
      if((c=='-'||c==' '|| c==','||c=='_')&(ch==' '||ch==','||ch='-'))
                {
                   ----------------------------
                   ----------------------------
                 }
```

The names are actually seperated by space.But the if condition fails to fetch the names.
Do i need to use nested if? or Any other  way to do this?

Comment: how did you determine `distancebetweenmiddlenameandfirstname` and `distancebetweenfamilynameandmiddlename` ? also can you put a debugger and confirm what exactly you are getting for those two values ?

Comment: I found the distnce by using UIMA framework.There are no problems with distance.But i just found that Fileinputstream reading space as question mark.I should verify why ? instead of space.I think i am skipping the file two times and read..

Comment: you might want to consider taking a look [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t683897-how-do-i-read-and-write-a-file-using-utf8.html)

Answer (score 1):

To 'AND' between if conditions, use '&&'.

In Java, '&' is a bitwise operator.

Answer (score 1):

Test with StringTokenizer class for obtain clean data. See this example:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to use && and not only & since the proper way to make a and in java is to use && and not only a single one

so your code looks like this

```
if (distancebetweenmiddlenameandfirstname == 1 && distancebetweenfamilynameandmiddlename == 1 )
```

Comment: i tried both the  conditions with &&. But the condition is not satisfied

Comment: and it gets you into the if statement?
and you are sure that distancebetweenmiddlenameandfirstname  and distancebetweenfamilynameandmiddlename  is 1?

Answer (score 0):

You say you found the distances with some other framework.

Are you sure of the values in these variables you're testing ?

How are these variables declared (what type or class) ?

Are you sure both the variables contain 1 ?

Comment: I found the distnce by using UIMA framework.There are no problems with distance.But i just found that Fileinputstream reading space as question mark.I should verify why ? instead of space...

Comment: You cannot say "there are no problems with distances" as your problem is either on checking these values or on calculating them. And an `if` is pretty straightforward...